# When developing a safari 10 extension in xcode, how do I do that independent of a macOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, safari-extension

I want to develop a Safari extension that simply runs in Safari without an associated Cocoa App on macOS. However, to get a "target" in xcode for a Safari Extension I have to have an existing macOS application. Why is that? Can I avoid it? Can I distribute the extension independent of the app? Can I test the extension on mobile/iOS Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you develop and test your extension in Xcode and then you are done, you can use the Extension Builder in Safari to make your extension independent from a MacOS app. Then you can submit your extension to the Safari extension Gallery

You should also check out the documentation
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UsingExtensionBuilder/UsingExtensionBuilder.html/)